# Dealing with the Cyclic Boundary Conditions of Frequency Domain Convolution in Order to Apply Linear Convolution

Tags: image-processing, python, dft, convolution, fast-convolution

```
def fft_convolution(image, kernel):
    imageC = image.copy()
    kSize = (kernel.size // 2)+1
    kernelShape = tuple(ti//2 for ti in kernel.shape)
    centery ,centerx = kernelShape
    imagePad = np.pad(image, kSize, mode = "edge")
    imageC = np.fft.fft2(imagePad)
    kernel= np.fft.fft2(kernel, imagePad.shape)
    output = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(np.multiply(imageC, kernel)))
    return output[kSize+centery:-kSize+centery, kSize+centerx:-kSize+centerx]
```

So my code currently takes an image M x N and kernel P x K
Pad on all sides the kernelSize // 2 + 1 and then make the kernel return from fft2 as the correct shape

I then crop using the shape of the kernel from my pad size, I dont really know why, something to do with circular convolutions maybe.

But this is really confusing and makes no sense to me especially when we get to cropping where I had to deal with artifacts of cylic convolution.

I am wondering what is the correct method to apply cropping and padding perfectly, taking into account i want my image to stay the same size and the edges must be interpolated rather than using constant zero values.

Comment: What would the corresponding code in spatial domain look like? "the edges must be interpolated rather than using constant zero values."? Extrapolated? From what?

Comment: Basically there is an image and kernel in spatial domain, i must prepare for the frequency domain multiplicaiton by convolution theorem. There is something I must do to the kernel in terms of alignign the axis which i am not sure about

Comment: Related to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79145.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a MATLAB function which is basically `conv2()` applied in Frequency Domain:

```
function [ mO ] = ImageConvFrequencyDomain( mI, mH, convShape )
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% [ mO ] = ImageConvFrequencyDomain( mI, mH, convShape )
% Applies Image Convolution in the Frequency Domain.
% Input:
%   - mI                -   Input Image.
%                           Structure: Matrix.
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double' (Single Channel).
%                           Range: (-inf, inf).
%   - mH                -   Filtering Kernel.
%                           Structure: Matrix.
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range: (-inf, inf).
%   - convShape         -   Convolution Shape.
%                           Sets the convolution shape.
%                           Structure: Scalar.
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range: {1, 2, 3}.
% Output:
%   - mI                -   Output Image.
%                           Structure: Matrix (Single Channel).
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range: (-inf, inf).
% References:
%   1.  MATLAB's 'conv2()' - https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html.
% Remarks:
%   1.  A
% TODO:
%   1.  
%   Release Notes:
%   -   1.0.000     29/04/2021  Royi Avital     RoyiAvital@yahoo.com
%       *   First release version.
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

CONV_SHAPE_FULL     = 1;
CONV_SHAPE_SAME     = 2;
CONV_SHAPE_VALID    = 3;

numRows     = size(mI, 1);
numCols     = size(mI, 2);

numRowsKernel = size(mH, 1);
numColsKernel = size(mH, 2);

switch(convShape)
    case(CONV_SHAPE_FULL)
        numRowsFft  = numRows + numRowsKernel - 1;
        numColsFft  = numCols + numColsKernel - 1;
        firstRowIdx = 1;
        firstColIdx = 1;
        lastRowIdx  = numRowsFft;
        lastColdIdx = numColsFft;
    case(CONV_SHAPE_SAME)
        numRowsFft  = numRows + numRowsKernel;
        numColsFft  = numCols + numColsKernel;
        firstRowIdx = ceil((numRowsKernel + 1) / 2);
        firstColIdx = ceil((numColsKernel + 1) / 2);
        lastRowIdx  = firstRowIdx + numRows - 1;
        lastColdIdx = firstColIdx + numCols - 1;
    case(CONV_SHAPE_VALID)
        numRowsFft = numRows;
        numColsFft = numCols;
        firstRowIdx = numRowsKernel;
        firstColIdx = numColsKernel;
        % The Kernel when transformed is shifted (Namely its (0, 0) is top
        % left not middle).
        lastRowIdx  = numRowsFft;
        lastColdIdx = numColsFft;
end

mO = ifft2(fft2(mI, numRowsFft, numColsFft) .* fft2(mH, numRowsFft, numColsFft), 'symmetric');
mO = mO(firstRowIdx:lastRowIdx, firstColIdx:lastColdIdx);


end
```

It is fully compatible and validated.
The full code is available on my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q74803 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q74803` folder).

If you want to apply image filter with Constant / Mirror or Replicate boundary mode just pad the image before the function and use `CONV_SHAPE_VALID` as `convShape`. Without padding the boundary condition applied is Periodic.